# Avoid XSS on a .getJSON using JQUERY

Tags: jquery-ui, xss

I need to pull in data from a JSON. I was able to do it like this:

```
$.getJSON(MACHINE + '/DailyFoundServlet?csfin=' + sDateFoundArray [i][CODE] + '&found=1&pubblic=true&callback=?', function(data) {

        sDateFoundArray [i][FOUND]=data;
        sDateFoundArray [i][NSER]++;

    })
```

This work fine but is not secure and the parameter 'callback' is vulnerable to XSS. How can I make sure I do not allow XSS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would examine using `$.post()` or `$.ajax()` if possible. So you mean secure by HTTPS? Is the page that makes this call using HTTPS? If so, then this AJAX call would be using HTTPS too. Otherwise, you will need to use the proper URL.

Comment: Can u explain me how to convert that .getJSON() to .ajax()? I try but i think that I am pretty noob. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I can help with that, but need to understand better what you're trying to accomplish. You can also look at: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ Depending on your needs, there are different AJAX methods that might work for you. Do you need to use GET, POST, or JSONP? Get is similar to just calling a webpage, and whatever data comes back, it's read. This is really easy to test, since you can just call it in your browser. Post you need to do more to test it.

Comment: Based on the snippet, it looks like you're performing this call within a loop. So it would also be helpful to see a more complete example. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers and sorry for my bad English. 
If I did not understand, that portion of code takes the "data" parameter and inserts it into an array then uses it to construct a graph. I have the XSS problem on url... where if i change the code after "callback=" with a good payload vector, i can see the allert. I

Comment: In example: if the url is "MYDOM/DailyFoundServlet?csfin=xxxxx&found=0&pubblicato=true&callback=jQuery172009821747812140869_1510330192767&_=1510330193196" when i change the url after "callback=" i can insert malicious code. 
I think I have to use JSONP but i am not 100% sure.

Comment: Yes, this would be vulnerable. Since you have not discussed what method your API can handle, I would again advise using POST versus GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am starting to suspect you have to use JSONP. There is no method to secure the callback, it's basically injecting a `<script>` into your page and executing the code. Just for reference: [jQuery JSONP Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216893/jquery-jsonp-security)

> I will start with this:
>
> There is no difference between jsonp way of working and `<Script src='whatever'> </script>`
>
> Now , use your imagination what are the pitfalls.

Consider this, it basically the same as your `.getJSON()`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: MACHINE + "/DailyFoundServlet",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  data: {
    'csfin': sDateFoundArray [i][CODE],
    'found': 1,
    'public': true
  },
  jsonp: "callback",
  sucess: function(data) {
    sDateFoundArray [i][FOUND]=data;
    sDateFoundArray [i][NSER]++;
  }
});
```

I also noticed in your post, the URL string shows: `pubblic=true` I was not sure if this was a typo or deliberate. I assumed it was a typo. The above code is still vulnerable to XSS.

As I mentioned, if you can, I would advise using POST as a more secure option. This would look like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: MACHINE + "/DailyFoundServlet",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    'csfin': sDateFoundArray [i][CODE],
    'found': 1,
    'public': true
  },
  method: "post",
  sucess: function(data) {
    sDateFoundArray [i][FOUND]=data;
    sDateFoundArray [i][NSER]++;
  }
});
```

This code works with the data that is returned and is expecting JSON data. If someone tries to send back other data, like a script block, it will not be interpreted and the function will fail. It would also be wise to check `data` for `length` or proper content type before passing it back into your variables. Something like:

```
  sucess: function(data) {
    if(data.length != 0){
      sDateFoundArray [i][FOUND]=data;
      sDateFoundArray [i][NSER]++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I
I was able to convert .getJSON to .ajax and, following your advice, I tried to set the "method: 'post'" and tried filtering with control over the length of the parameter (i was trying something similar on the type the object). None of the two tips, however, solves the problem and if loading the url directly from the browser by pasting after the callback parameter this code "% 3chtml% 3e <img + src% 3da + onerror% 3d" alert (document.cookie) "> </ html>% 00 "the alert is still invoked.

Comment: Thank u so much. I change the SERVLET method in "doPost" and now all work fine! Thank u for advices!